# CSS - Center position is not working in IE having absolute position

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have placed 3 `div`. First parent having `css` like position relative and it is taking full width of viewport. 2nd children is having absolute position to cover all area of parent. The 3rd children is also having absolute position with `margin: 0 auto`.

```css
.slide-block {
  position: relative;
}

.slide-block .slide-block-center-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.slide-block .slide-block-content {
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-block">
  <div class="slide-block-center-wrapper">
    <div class="slide-block-content">
      ...some slide caption content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, `.slide-block-content` is not appearing in center in `IE` browser. It is appearing in center in `chrome` and `mozilla`.

Comment: It's not appearing in center in `chrome` and `mozilla` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to solve it like below. For the element to be vertically centered the height needs to be known. I also changed the 3rd child to inline block and used the transform to horizontally center it. If you only need to vertically center it, you can remove the `left: 50%` and change the `translate` to `translateY`.

```css
.slide-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.slide-block .slide-block-center-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.slide-block .slide-block-content {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 1180px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-block">
  <div class="slide-block-center-wrapper">
    <div class="slide-block-content">
      ...some slide caption content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution. It very close that I was not able to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
 margin: 0px;      /* Added */
 padding: 0px;     /* Added */

}

.slide-block {
  align-items: center;  /* Added */
  }

.slide-block .slide-block-center-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.slide-block .slide-block-content {
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding:0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;  /* Added */
  transform: translate(0,-50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-block">
  <div class="slide-block-center-wrapper">
    <div class="slide-block-content">
      ...some slide caption content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try by adding `justify-content: center` to your `.slide-block .slide-block-content`. Hope this will work.

```
.slide-block .slide-block-content {
justify-content: center
}
```